# $P[X_n \in [\alpha, \beta]]\geq 1-\epsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, distribution-theory

Let $(X_n)$  r.v. such that converge in distribution to $X$.

(a) Prove that for each $\epsilon > 0$ exists $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha <\beta$, such that
$$P[X_n \in [\alpha, \beta]]\geq 1-\epsilon \ \ \ \text{for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$}.$$

(b) Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Prove that if $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to a r.v. $Y$, then
$$\frac{S_n}{n} \xrightarrow{P}0.$$

I think (a) is from definition since $X_n$ converge in distribution to $X$ then $\{X_n\}$ is tight and hence for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha <\beta$ such that

$$P[X_n \in [\alpha, \beta]]\geq 1-\epsilon \ \ \ \text{for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$}.$$

Is this right?

For the second statement I'm stuck. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, a) boils down to tightness of sequence converging in distribution, as you said. As a hint for b), note that $\frac{S_n}{n} = \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. You know that $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $Y$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to $0$ (which is a constant). Do you know any result concerning such type of convergence?

Comment: oooh... I guess is the Slutsky's theorem right?

Comment: Exactly, this will give you $\frac{S_n}{n} \to 0$ in distribution and it is a known fact that when sequence converges to a constant in distribution, it converges to the same constant in probability.

Comment: I see... I understood everything but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to $0$, it is supposed to be a probability convergence to apply the Slutsky's theorem, right?

Comment: More like just $Y_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ (i.e $\mathbb P(Y_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})=1$), it's enough (but I've never seen someone bother about it, deterministic sequences are random, too (in appriopriate sense))

Comment: I must define something like $P[Y_n \leq y] = \begin{cases} 0 & y  \leq 1/\sqrt{n}  \\ 1 &  y > 1\sqrt{n} \end{cases}$ i.e. $P[Y_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}]=1$

Comment: Yes that is right. Thank you!